# Route Group in Lumen error Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::group()

Tags: php, laravel, routes, lumen, lumen-5.2

I have declared a route group in laravel/lumen like so:

```
$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/details', 'UserController@details');
});
```

all contents of route file web.php are like so:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$app = app();

$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});


$app->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/details', 'UserController@details');
});
```

on making a call to http://THE_URL/

I get an error `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::group()`

[image: ERROR]

How do I add route group with a middleware ?

Comment: Did you check this? https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups although it doesn't seem to be different from what you did.

Comment: wait! do you have to add those `$app = app();

$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});` ?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Yes I checked the URL and the part you mentioned in the second comment is the default route defined in lumen also I did add `$app = app();` as it was not found

Comment: No, I think thats where you have a problem. You don't need to create the `$app` variable. Laravel knows how they managed to create that so you can use. At least on my lumen project, this variable is ready for use.

Comment: Wait, the `$router` variable is used in Lumen 5.2? if thats the case then use the variable you meet as the default in the file.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Oh I found the solution should I post it here if that helps someone, or should I delete the question ?

Comment: no post the solution here and mark it as answered

Comment: In documentation there is `$app->get()` but in reality needs to use `$router->get()`

Answer (score 5):

Actually as @Aine said in Lumen 5.5+ you should change:

`LumenPassport::routes($this->app);`

to

`LumenPassport::routes($this->app->router);`

Application does not have `group()` method anymore.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem, with upgrading Lumen from 5.4 to 5.5

In the [docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0), it states:

> **Updating The Routes File**
>
> After updating your bootstrap/app.php file,
>   you should update your routes/web.php file to use the  $router
>   variable instead of the $app variable:
>
> $router->get('/hello', function () {
>       return 'Hello World'; });

For me, this meant lots of updating, where ever $app was used in the routing.

```
$app->get()                     => $router->get()
$app->group()                   => $router->group()
$app->post()/patch()/delete()   => $router->post()/patch()/delete()

// Inside functions    
$app->group([...], function () use ($app)
=>
$router->group([...], function () use ($router)

// And even in some other files
$app = app();
$app->get();
    =>
$app = app();
$router = $app->router;
$router->get();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was actually facing the issue on Lumen and not Laravel.

Comment: Me too :). I just updated my answer to say Lumen instead of Laravel. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution to the problem:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
        return "API";
    });

    $router->post('/signin','UserController@signin');
    $router->post('/signup','UserController@signup');

    $router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($router) {
        $router->get('/details', 'UserController@details');
    });
});
```

In order to group routs we have to use:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () use ($router) {
        $router->get('/details', 'UserController@details');
});
```

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho What problem are you facing ?